# reprocess ssl certbot , when a alias domain fails but certificate is generated, no mode certonly

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I've start certbot process with:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

but I forgot to add 'www.example.com' in 'servernam' nginx virtualsite for example.com

```
server { 
        (...)
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        (...)
}
```

then i've got the certificate but not the auto complet process to config my nginx with ssl

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for examle.com
tls-sni-01 challenge for www.example.com
Cleaning up challenges
Cannot find a VirtualHost matching domain www.example.com. In order for Certbot to correctly perform the challenge please add a corresponding server_name directive to your nginx configuration: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
   configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
   secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
   also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
   making regular backups of this folder is ideal.
```

It's like I wrote just:

```
cerbot --certonly --standalone -d example.com
```

because I have just the certificate, now the config on nginx it's ok, i can lauch again the process and overwrite all the old values ? is there a problem with Let's Encrypt Certificate Authority , call again a new certificate for the same domain? what is the solution? delete all again, or complete the rest of process ( nginx config) by hand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with cerbot to launch again the ssl for domains already created. In my case when domains fails, and it's the first time you use  certbot. Nginx config is changed but not totally , so when you try second time that will be complet and update nginx config. Certbot just update the config for the domain, and comment the old lines that it think are duplicated and inserting the new ones , addigng #manage by Certbod, so when you need to renovate your certificate Cerbot can change smartly the lines.

Example my nginx config ,with the first try, and second:

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


# Redirect non-https traffic to https
# if ($scheme != "https") {
#     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
# } # managed by Certbot
```